# SSL Certificate for Web Service Client

Tags: ssl, windows-services, windows-server-2008

I am trying to create a Web Service client to connect to a Web Service, I have been given a Non-English document on how to connect to the web service which I have translated using Google translate (yes bad idea I know, I've asked a person who speaks the language and is also a developer to translate it for me but I am waiting for him to get back to me).  The connection is secured "using a two-sided SSL connection".

I am supposed to get a SSL certificate (two actually one for test and one for prod) and send them the pubic key.  They've sent me their public keys.

I plan to call their web services from a Windows Service.  So what am I generating my SSL certificate against?  If it was a web site it would be for mywebsite.mydomain.com but this is for a Windows Service.

I am lost as to why both sides need SSL Certificates but that may be a different question.

Answer (score 1):

The server side needs a certificate. You could use a self-generate certificate. The side-effect is that the browser will say that the server is not thrusted. So if you need to get a rid of the not-trusted error you need to buy a valid certificate from a certificate authority.

In the client side you need a certificate only if you want to login the client thru a certificate. there are other methods for client login. 
But if you insist in using the client-side X509 certificate dont forget to change your application (or your service)  web.config. In Visual Studio it always auto-generate the webservice call without security so you need to add or change the customBinding to include httpsTransport tag as below.

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
      <binding name="MYWEBBINDING">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Digest" requireClientCertificate="true" />
      </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

and reference it in the client section

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://WEBSERVICESERVER/WEBSERVICE/WEBSERVICE.asmx"
    binding="MYWEBBINDING" bindingConfiguration="WEBSERVICESoap"
    contract="WEBSVCPROXY.WEBSERVICESoap" name="WEBSERVICESoap" />
</client>
```